# NSLayoutConstraint with animation block

Tags: objective-c, animation, autolayout

I have problem with animation and NSLayout, the constant is not updating at the first time and . Only on the second time it takes the correct values.

here is my code:

```
if(gb == self.graphBar0){
                         self.gb0HeightConstraint.constant = newConstant;
                         [self.graphBar0 setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
                         [self.graphLabel0 setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
                     }else if(gb == self.graphBar1){
                         self.gb1HeightConstraint.constant = newConstant;
                         [self.graphBar1 setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
                         [self.graphLabel1 setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
                     }else if(gb == self.graphBar2){
                         self.gb2HeightConstraint.constant = newConstant;
                         [self.graphBar2 setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
                         [self.graphLabel2 setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
                     }

 [UIView animateWithDuration:duration
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
                 animations:^{
                     if(gb == self.graphBar0){

                         [self.graphBar0 layoutIfNeeded];
                         [self.graphLabel0 layoutIfNeeded];
                     }else if(gb == self.graphBar1){

                         [self.graphBar1 layoutIfNeeded];
                         [self.graphLabel1 layoutIfNeeded];
                     }else if(gb == self.graphBar2){

                         [self.graphBar2 layoutIfNeeded];
                         [self.graphLabel2 layoutIfNeeded];
                     }
                     [gb setBackgroundColor:newBarColor];
                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     if(gb == self.graphBar0){
                         self.oldConstant0 = newConstant;
                     }
                     if(gb == self.graphBar1){
                         self.oldConstant1 = newConstant;
                     }
                     if(gb == self.graphBar2){
                         self.oldConstant2 = newConstant;
                     }
                 }];
```

is there anything I'm missing?

Thanks,
Missa

Comment: explain `'not updating at the first time'`. cuz it all seems like it should animate.

Comment: in the first run the constant seams to be same value not the one that I'm setting before animation so it animates but with a wrong value, and when I tap on the view second time it takes the correct value and animate according to that value.

Comment: so... erm... what is `newConstant` the first time?

Comment: the new constraint is the value that being set programmatically before animation occurs

Comment: obviously :P anyways... maybe if you shared your project, i could just look at it rather than ask this and that. one thing i can say for sure is that the problem does not lie in the code you have shared.

Answer (score 0):

Change `setNeedsUpdateConstraints` to `layoutIfNeeded` before the animation block.

Update the constraints in the animation instead of the completion block and call `layoutIfNeeded` just after.